# xts objects lose xts class when subsetting

Tags: r, subset, xts

Consider the following.

```
junk1.xts <- xts(c(0:10), as.yearqtr("1975 Q1") + 0.25*(0:10))
junk2.xts <- xts(c(30:0), as.yearqtr("1970 Q1") + 0.25*(0:30))
junk2a.xts <- junk2.xts[index(junk1.xts),]
class(junk1.xts)
class(junk2.xts)
class(junk2a.xts)
```

The first two class statements result in:

```
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

but the third results in:

```
[1] "zoo"
```

Why? Is this normal or a bug? What's the best way to prevent it and preserve the xts class for the third object?

Comment: I don't observe this unusual behaviour with xts 0.10-0

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. I am trying to add a labeling capability, modeled after the one in Hmisc, to xts objects. In doing so, I had defined a function for `[.xts`. It worked initially, but then I made some efficiency changes. One of them broke the function.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: I'd be interested to know your use case.  There might be a way to do what you want without overwriting `[.xts`.  Even if there isn't, remember that the "x" in xts stands for "eXtensible".  So you could subclass xts and just override the `[.xts` function to do what you want.

Comment: I'm starting up a research project involving time-series analyses, with several types of time series -- macroeconomic aggregates, price indices, etc. -- from disparate sources. To keep track of the variables I am incorporating labels and units into xts objects at both the object and variable levels. All are stored as xtsAttributes. At the object level they include scalar "label" and "units" items applying to the entire xts object; at the variable level they include lists of variable names (var.labels) and units (unit.labels)